# Options in a geo google-chart

Tags: google-visualization, polymer

I'm trying to use Polymer's [google-chart](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart) component to create a geo chart with the marker display mode, however, the component keeps showing an error of `google.load is not a function`.

I think the chart is being bound to the DOM before a call to the Google Maps API is completed but I'm not totally sure. Has anyone else had success making marker or text geo charts with the `google-chart` component?

Here's a repro of the issue using the [marker](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#marker-geocharts) and [text](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#text-geocharts) geochart examples: https://jsbin.com/mewahibane/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `google-chart` library.
Recently there was a change where a `google-chart-loader` element was added to deal with some recent [issues](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/issues/118) with the google charts library.
Maybe this causes an issue with the GeoChart library.

As a workaround add this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` above the `google-chjart` import. This should fix it. See here:

https://jsbin.com/gejipiqehu/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for tracking down what was causing it!

Answer (score -2):

What about this code ? >> https://jsbin.com/tabahu/edit?html,output

i am trying to add marker on google-chart. just copy code from this documentation.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#marker-geocharts

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to use a `google-chart` component from the Polymer library. I already know that plain JS will work just fine.